# How to build GTK2 on the Mac OS X EI Captain?

Tags: linux, x11, osx, compiling, gcc

I tried to build GTK2 to Mac OS X EI Captain from source code. But by the environment variable (INCLUDE?), an error occurred and I failed to build.
Please help me by advices?

Doesn't someone have the man who encountered to the following error?

```
hash.c:111:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'free'
  obstack_init (&htab->mem_pool);
  ^
./obstack.h:294:65: note: expanded from macro 'obstack_init'
                  (void () (long)) obstack_chunk_alloc, (void (*) (void *)) obstack_chunk_free)
                                                                              ^
hash.c:53:28: note: expanded from macro 'obstack_chunk_free'
#define obstack_chunk_free free
                           ^
```

I think that gcc can't find include file malloc.h .
I don't understand that it is correct.

First, I downloaded following packages.
gtk+-2.24.30,
glib-2.28.0,atk-1.29.2,pango-1.20.0,gdk-pixbuf-2.21.3,
gettext-0.10.40

I executed the following.

```
$ cd gettext-0.10.40
$ ./configure
$ make
```

Then, the following error occurred.

```
hash.c:111:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'free'
  obstack_init (&htab->mem_pool);
  ^
./obstack.h:294:65: note: expanded from macro 'obstack_init'
                  (void () (long)) obstack_chunk_alloc, (void (*) (void *)) obstack_chunk_free)
                                                                              ^
hash.c:53:28: note: expanded from macro 'obstack_chunk_free'
#define obstack_chunk_free free
                           ^
hash.c:121:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'free' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  free (htab->table);
  ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

malloc.h of usual distribution of the Linux exists at /usr/include but malloc.h of the Mac OS X EI Captain exists at /usr/include/sys.
So I executed the following.

```
$ cd gettext-0.10.40
$ env CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include/sys ./configure
$ make
```

However, the same error occurred.
It is too hard for me to handle.

Thank you.

Comment: The problem has solved by oneself. I downloaded gtk-osx-build-setup.sh from (https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/OSX/Building), and executed as following.
$ ./gtk-osx-build-setup.sh
$ jhbuild bootstrap
I must remove a lot of errors but could install GTK2 in Mac OS X EI Captain below basically.
$ jhbuild build meta-gtk-osx-bootstrap meta-gtk-osx-core
I must remove a lot of errors but could install GTK3 in Mac OS X EI Captain below basically too.
$ jhbuild build meta-gtk-osx-bootstrap meta-gtk-osx-gtk3